# JMeter - How do I get latency in the aggregate report?

Tags: jmeter

I just want to get the aggregate report include a column for latency.

I have already tried `uncommenting jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true` in `bin/jmeter.properties`.

I am currently using `JMeter 3.3`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: 
A little hack I tried that kind of worked was adding a JSR223 PostProcessor with the following 3 lines of code:

```
long startTime = prev.getStartTime();
long latency = prev.getLatency();
prev.setEndTime(startTime + latency);
```

I say kind of worked because it is a hack and even though it was able to correctly reset the average column from load time to latency, it started throwing off the throughput values.

The end goal in my case is just to get the latency along with the other values by running the CMDRunner.jar on the JTL file to output the summary results CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't .

Alternatively why not use the Web Report that exists since 3.0 and that provides a lot of rich information much better than all existing listeners.

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is definitely useful but seems a little too elaborate for my purpose. 

The end goal in my case is just to get the latency along with the other values by running the CMDRunner.jar on the JTL file to output the summary results CSV file.

Comment: A little hack I tried that kind of worked was adding a JSR223 PostProcessor with the following 3 lines of code:

`long startTime = prev.getStartTime();
long latency = prev.getLatency();
prev.setEndTime(startTime + latency);`

I say kind of worked because it is a hack and even though it was able to correctly reset the average column from load time to latency, it started throwing off the throughput values.